# Should i use logging module or logging class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I write big program with many modules. In same module I wish use logging. What best practice for logging in Python?
Should I use import standart logging module and use it in every my file:

```
#proxy_control.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging


class ProxyClass():

    def check_proxy():
        pass
        logging.basicConfig(filename='proxy.log', level=logging.INFO)
        logging.info('Proxy work fine')
```

Or maybe i should write one MyLog() class inherit from default logging and use it from all my other modules?

```
#proxy_control.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import MyLog


class ProxyClass():

    def check_proxy():
        pass
        Mylog.send_log('Proxy work fine')


#my_log.py
#!/usr/env/bin python3

import logging


class MyLog():
     def send_log(value):
         pass
```

Comment: The Python logging Howto might be handy to answer your questions: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you, but I read doc about logging and found only info how i should use default logging library and modules. I whant to know what best practices for constructing logging structure in program. What often choose and why in real project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A typical convention is to define a logger at the top of every module that requires logging and then use that logger object throughout the module.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This way, loggers will follow your package names (ie. `package.subpackage.module`).  This is useful in the logging module because loggers propagate messages upwards based on the logger name (ie. `parent.child` will pass messages up to `parent`).  This means that you can do all your configuration at the top level logger and it will get messages from all the sub-loggers in your package.  Or, if someone else is using your library, it will be very easy for them to configure which logging messages they get from your library because it will have a consistent namespace.

For a library, you typically don't want to show logging messages unless the user explicitly enables them.  Python logging will automatically log to stderr unless you set up a handler, so you should add a [NullHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#nullhandler) to your top-level logger.  This will prevent the messages from automatically being printed to stderr.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

**NOTE** - The NullHandler was added in Python2.7, for earlier versions, you'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed reply. But my main module located on remote server and other modules on my local PC. I should  split logging on local and remote? Or I can do logging like your answer with remote server too?

Comment: @DenisSavenko Python's logging module has support for more than local IO (streams/files) handlers - see the SocketHandler and SMTPHandler for examples, and you can even write your own - so you can have all your logs in the same place even with a distributed architecture. In fact with proper configuration you can even have both local logging to stream or file AND remote logging at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Use the logging module,  and leave logging configuration to your application's entry point (modules should not configure logging by themselves).